# substr & index - extract from string $2 until the last string of the line

Tags: indexing, awk, substr

I have multiple files from which I want from a specific line to extract from string $2 until the last string of line or until the end of line   (it could be one more string after $2, or it could be more)

So what I thought is use awk, substr and index, but I dont know how to write the index part so it could print until the end of line or until the last string of line

EXAMPLE

**input:**

```
DATA USA CALIFORNIA
DATA CANADA NORTH Quebec city
DATA AMERICA Washington DC
```

**output**

```
USA CALIFORNIA
CANADA NORTH Quebec city
AMERICA Washington DC
```

Code:

```
awk '{num=NR; var=substr($2, index($2, " ")+1, NF)}'
```

But this doesn't work.

Any help would be more than appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you have one space between the words, use

```
cut -sd' ' -f2-  inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `$1 = ""` to remove the first field, then print the updated line.

```
awk '{$1 = ""; print}'
```

The above will however print a space at the start of each line. If you want to remove that space:

```
awk '{$1 = ""; $0=substr($0, 2); print}'
```

Comment: It'll also change all chains of white space to individual blank chars so YMMV with that.

Comment: @EdMorton Oups. Perhaps I shouldn't tinker with other peoples answers :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo just `$1 = ""` causes the issue, the stuff you added to the answer wouldn't affect that, it'd just fix the additional leading blank issue.

Comment: @EdMorton Ah... I thought it was my addition :) Thanks again.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly. Good job. Voted!

Answer (score 1):

From your examples, it seems that you only want to remove `$1`. In that case you could use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to remove it:

```
sed -E 's/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]//'
```

- `[^[:space:]]+` - match 1 or more non whitespace characters
- `[[:space:]]` - followed by a whitespace character

Substitiute with an empty string (the ending`//`).

Comment: Exactly. Voted!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing anything from your code, so that might be why "this doesn't work". Assuming that's not the problem, please edit your question to tell us what the problem is you need help with as "this doesn't work" is famously the worst possible problem statement when asking for help with software or anything else in life in general.

Having said that, regarding `index($2, " ")` - that's trying to find a space within a field when fields are separated by spaces so obviously that can never succeed. ITYM `index($0, " ")` and then `substr($2...` would be `substr($0...`. I'm not sure what you were thinking by having `NF` (the number of fields in the line) at the end of the `substr()` - maybe you meant `length()` (the number of chars in the line) but that'd also be wrong (and unnecessary) since that'd be more chars than are left after the substr() and just going til the end of the string as you want is substr()s default behavior anyway.

To fix your existing code try this:

```
$ awk '{num=NR; var=substr($0, index($0, " ")+1); print var}' file
USA CALIFORNIA
CANADA NORTH Quebec city
AMERICA Washington DC
```

or more robustly in case of most regexp FS and most input values:

```
$ awk '{num=NR; var=substr($0, match($0, FS)+1); print var}' file
USA CALIFORNIA
CANADA NORTH Quebec city
AMERICA Washington DC
```

The above and all other answers so far would fail if you're using the default `FS` and your input starts with blanks since given input like:

```
<blank>X<blank>Y
```

$1 is X and $2 is Y so if you want to print from Y on then you can't just delete whatever's before the first blank as $1 comes AFTER any leading whitespace when the default FS is used.

You also can't rely on using `index()` since it only matches strings while a multi-char FS is a regexp, nor can you rely on using `match()` since a single-char FS is a literal character.

So a robust solution to `extract from string $2 until the last string of the line` would have to handle:

1. FS being a blank to handle leading/trailing spaces and match any white space between fields,
2. Any other single-char FS as a literal character.
3. Any multi-char FS as a regexp.
4. FS being null in which case there's just 1 field, $1.

Let us know if you actually need that.

Comment: You are right. Right! Voted!

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
awk '{num=NR; var=substr($2, index($2, " ")+1, NF)}'
```

has three issues, firstly you are storing what substr returns into variable, but do not print it, secondly you assume desired length is number of fields, which is not case, thirdly `$2` is respectively USA, CANADA, AMERICA, whilst you want also further fields.

After commencing repairs to your code it become

```
awk '{num=NR; var=substr($0, index($0, " ")+1); print var}' file.txt
```

which for

```
DATA USA CALIFORNIA
DATA CANADA NORTH Quebec city
DATA AMERICA Washington DC
```

gives output

```
USA CALIFORNIA
CANADA NORTH Quebec city
AMERICA Washington DC
```

that being, if you do not have to use `index` AT ANY PRICE you might use `sub` function to get desired output and more concise code following way

```
awk '{sub(/^[^ ]+ /,"");print}' file.txt
```

it does replace start of string (`^`) followed by 1-or-more (`+`) non (`^`)-spaces and space using empty string, i.e. delete it, then `print` such changed line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the input:

```
$ cat input
DATA  USA CALIFORNIA                             # 2x spaces between DATA and USA
DATA CANADA   NORTH Quebec city
        DATA AMERICA Washington , DC             # starts with 1x tab
  DATA South Korea Seoul                         # starts with 2x spaces
```

Another `awk` variation:

```
awk '
{ print substr($0,index($0,$2)) }                # strip off 1st field by finding starting point of 2nd field
' input

# or as a one-liner sans comments

awk '{ print substr($0,index($0,$2)) }' input
```

**NOTES:**

- for this particular example there's no need for the `num` and `var` variables so they've been removed
- this assumes the 2nd field is not a substring of the 1st field; if the 2nd field is any of `D / A / T / DA / AT / TA / DAT / ATA / DATA` then `index()` will match on the same string in the 1st field (`DATA`) which means we'll fail to strip off the 1st field

This generates:

```
USA CALIFORNIA
CANADA   NORTH Quebec city
AMERICA Washington , DC
South Korea Seoul
```

---

Addressing the scenario where the 2nd field could be a substring of the 1st field ...

Sample input:

```
$ cat input2
DATA  DA   USA CALIFORNIA                         #  DA is substring of DATA
DATA A    CANADA NORTH Quebec city                #   A is substring of DATA
        DATA TA   AMERICA Washington, DC          #  TA is substring of DATA
  DATA DAT  South Korea Seoul                     # DAT is substring of DATA
```

A couple `awk` ideas:

```
awk '
{ match($0,$1)                                        # find 1st field location
  $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                        # strip off 1st field; this will not strip off any field separators so we need to ...
  print substr($0,index($0,$1))                       # find start of new 1st field (old 2nd field)
}
' input2

# replace match()/substr() with substr()/index()/length()

awk '
{ $0=substr($0,index($0,$1)+length($1))               # find 1st field location and length; this strips off 1st field but not the trailing field separator(s) so we still need to ... 
  print substr($0,index($0,$1))                       # find start of new 1st field (old 2nd field)
}
' input2
```

These both generate:

```
DA   USA CALIFORNIA
A    CANADA NORTH Quebec city
TA   AMERICA Washington, DC
DAT  South Korea Seoul
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='^[ \t]*[^ \t]+[ \t]+' OFS=
> ```

```
USA CALIFORNIA
CANADA NORTH Quebec city
AMERICA Washington DC
```